# unable to hide and show a particular table row with the same id names inside a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a website and there are some pages containing the `<div>` tags as the wrapper of `<table>`. A `<tr>` of each table contains a `<form>` and another `<tr>` contains some `<a>` tags. I am using these anchor tags to make buttons just to add hide and show  functionality. Whenever some new data is fetched from database, the set of said `html` structure is created dynamically. Every `<div>` contains the same `id` and every `<tr>` also containing the `<form>` assigned the same `id`. Below is my example `html`for the better explanation.

**HTML**

```
<div class='static_archive'>   // First Wrapper
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Some data</td>
         <td>Some data</td>
         <td>
            <a id='show_hide_details' href='#'>Show/Hide Button</a>
         </td> 
      </tr>

      <tr id='form_container'> 
         <td colspan='3'>
            <form>
               <input type='text' name'first' />
               <input type='text' name'second' />
               <input type='text' name'third' /> 
            </form>
         </td> 
      </tr>  
   </table>
</div>

<div class='static_archive'>  // Second Wrapper
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td>Some data</td>
         <td>Some data</td>
         <td>
            <a id='show_hide_details' href='#'>Show/Hide Button</a>
         </td> 
      </tr>

      <tr id='form_container'> 
         <td colspan='3'>
            <form>
               <input type='text' name'first' />
               <input type='text' name'second' />
               <input type='text' name'third' /> 
            </form>
         </td> 
      </tr>  
   </table>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("#form_container").hide();

     $("#show_hide_details").click(function(){

          $("#form_container").toggle();

     });      
});
```

As soon as the page loads, `$("#form_container").hide();` hides all the `<tr>` containing the `<form>`. By clicking `hide/show` button with the toggle effect, hides and shows the every content with the same id.

I want to show only one `form` at a time when a particular button is `hide/show` button is pressed. How can i control such behavior?

With a new record fetched, a new `DIV` is created with only one table inside it. And the table contains only one form. The table row containing the form needs to be hide/show.

Here is the jsfiddle with my code structure [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U6KQ/1/)

Every clicked `hide/show` should effects the respective form.

I have edited my post. Please have a look now.

Comment: Every <div> contains the same id and every <tr> also containing the <form> assigned the same id this can never happen

Comment: You shouldn't be using the same ID on multiple elements, that's what classes are for.

Comment: Could you give the sample http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: You should hide your element by default using css display none instead of removing visibility with jquery on the first line in the function

Comment: here is the jsfiddle.. http://jsfiddle.net/5U6KQ/

Comment: as far as i know its working fine in jsfiddle. BUT with the same id if you add more forms, its going to show all the forms matching the ID you pass-in... you should really use class name for each forms

Comment: @AndyHolmes hiding it with js rather than css means that if js is turned off then the form will be shown

Comment: @SomnathKharat you did not understand what is my requirement. Please have a look on my post. I just edited it.

Comment: @Rebbeca <tr id='form_container'> u cant have tr with same ids whether they are dynamically created.see the render html and see the ids dynamically created

Comment: I tried using unique classes but it does not work. I can figure out it myself but there is something little missing that i am unable to figure out right now.

Comment: @AndyHolmes i can use but the problem is, hidding with css still occupies the space.

Comment: @Rebbeca display: none; doesn't occupy the space, visibility: hidden; does. And yeah if you're catering for people who may be turning js off then hiding that way is fine

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$(this)` to do the toggle with particular block.

```
$(this).closest('tr').next("#form_container").toggle();
```

You **should not use same id for multiple elements**, assign class and use that

```
$(this).closest('tr').next(".form_container").toggle();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u want this or may this help u.

You can not have same id's for different controls.So u can have id's staring with same string

You can use [`^`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("[id^='form_container']").hide();
     $("#show_hide_details").click(function(){
           $(this).parents().next("tr").toggle();
     });      
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Somnath_k/5U6KQ/4/)

Comment: Here is the fiddle of your code [http://jsfiddle.net/5U6KQ/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/5U6KQ/2/). Every time clicking hide/show should show the respective form. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show all of them hidden first. Obviously, you have to replace the id's with class.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".form_container").hide();


     $(".show_hide_details").click(function(){

         $(this).parents("tr").next().toggle();

     });      
});
```

Comment: Yes. As soon as the page loads, all forms will be hidden. By clicking respective form hide/show will show only its form. I know i can do it using inline jquery. But trying to do it if i have external js file.